# How to trim a part of a string which is inside double quotes, and save it in a particular string using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How to replace a part of a string which is inside double quotes, and save it in a particular string using PHP?

Example:

If a string has the value

```
$str = 'HS_NAME="Easymoney"    # WIFI function Name';
```

How can I replace the data which comes between the double quotes from the string?

i want to replace *easymoney* with any other string such as 
`$str1="stackoverflow"` ; 
so the string output will become
`$str = 'HS_NAME="stackoverflow" # WIFI function Name'`;

Comment: can you specify the boundaries of your string? it's not clear where it start and ends

Comment: Your question is very confusing. *trim* means to remove whitespace around a string. *replace* means to put something else in place of the substring, but you haven't said what you want to replace it with. What is it you really want to do?

Comment: i want to replace easymoney with any other string such as $str="stackoverflow" ;         so the string output will become   $str = 'HS_NAME="stackoverflow"    # WIFI function Name';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to search and replace in the string.

```
<?php

$str = 'HS_NAME="Easymoney" # WIFI function Name';

$result = preg_replace('#"(.*)"#','"replacement"',$str);

print $result . PHP_EOL;
```

will output

```
HS_NAME="replacement" # WIFI function Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string by this code .

```
<?php

$string = "'text'" ; // your old string that you need to change it

$counter = strlen($string) ; // length counter
$NewString = "Text will be replace" ; // new string to put it instead of the string var 
$Single_qoute = substr($string,0,1) ; // first car of the old string like single quote or double 
$string = $Single_qoute.$NewString.$Single_qoute; // your output
?>
```